# JavaScript: Distinguish between native and non-native member

Tags: javascript, function

Is there any way to detect whether a given function, say `Array.prototype.forEach`, is a native function (e.g. the browser implements ECMAScript5) or a function added by a page's JavaScript script(s)?

Comment: The usual question here is "why do you need to know?" Also, I think you mean "built–in" function, since native functions include those added by javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting it to the console and seeing what comes up there.

Answer (score 1):

I would say : alert(*function*);

If it pops as "native code" then it is native code...

Comment: ECMA-262 §15.3.4.2—Function.prototype.toString— `An implementation-dependent representation of the function is returned.`. Just because it's common to include the phrase "native code" doesn't make it reliable.

Comment: It might be too subtle for me but I *think* my answer is OK for his question (is it browser implented or added by a .js page ?)

Comment: The phrase "native code" is included **by convention** (i.e. it is not required by any open, formal standard) in the string representation of many host methods and objects. Host objects are not native objects, so clearly the term "native" in that phrase has a different meaning to "native" as defined in ECMA-262 §4.3.6. Note also that functions created by user code are also "native".

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the enumerable property of a native method.

```
function isNative(prop){
    var op= this.prototype;
    if(prop in op){
        for(var p in op){
            if(p=== prop){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return null;
}
isNative.call(Array, 'map');
```

Comment: Except that in ES5 users can create non-enumerable properties too. And you should change *isNative* to *isBuiltin*, since your *isNative* function is a native ECMAScript object.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a technique that seems to work in browsers I've tried (though I don't think it's specified by a standard):

```
function checkMethodType(m) {
    if (!m) {
        return("doesn't exist");
    } else if (m.toString().search(/\[native code\]/) != -1) {
        return("native");
    } else {
        return("non-native");
    }
}

checkMethodType(Array.prototype.forEach);    // native in modern browsers
checkMethodType(Array.prototype.myMethod);   // non-native
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GJJqQ/.

This technique is non-standard and is not guaranteed to be reliable.  In fact, you can fool it if you want to by putting the [native code] string in a non-native method.  But, it might be useful anyway depending upon what you want it for.  I'm not aware of any 100% reliable method.

Comment: Provided the browser supports function decompiling(and displaying `[native code]`) I believe my answer is relatively bulletproof....

Answer (score 0):

For those suggesting the "native code" method:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'function slice() {\n    [native code]\n}';
}

var foo = new Foo();
alert(foo);

/* Shows:
**   function Array() {
**       [native code]
**   }
*/
```

Some browsers will also include the phrase "native code" for host objects.

Als, according to ECMA-262 §4.3.6:

> **native object**
>
> object in an ECMAScript implementation whose
>     semantics are fully defined by this   specification rather than by the
>     host environment.
>
> NOTE Standard native objects are defined in this specification. Some
>   native objects are built-in; others may be constructed during the
>   course of execution of an ECMAScript program.

So if an *Array.prototype.forEach* method was added by user code, then it **is** a native object. Perhaps the OP really meant built–in method.

Comment: ok but this example is totally made up for the sole purpose of providing a counter example. this shouldnt interfere with "real life" testings

Comment: What do you mean "real life testing"? A user added function can mimic being "native code", they can also be non-enumerable in ES5.

Comment: I'm still trying to work out what the OP meant by "native". In javasript there is native, built-in (which is a sub-set of native) and host. Host objects are a world unto themselves and can do anything they like, include throw errors when logic says they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect but pretty much as close as you can get.  I believe Opera(**?some version?**) doesn't properly support decompiling of `Function`s, nor does Opera mobile.  It You call what you want to do.  It also avoids RobG's evil hackery.

```
function isNative(obj){
  var toString = obj.toString;
  delete obj.toString;
  var ret =  obj.toString().match(/\s*function\s+([a-z0-9]+)\s*\(\s*\)\s*{\s*\[native code\]/i)
  obj.toString = toString;
  return ret;
}
```

It also returns the functions name for example

```
 isNative(window.Array)[1] = "Array"
```